# node: illegal access error - using es6 proxies

Tags: node.js, proxy, ecmascript-6

When I run my code with node 0.10.26, I'm getting an 'illegal access' error when using ES6 proxies. It doesn't happen with node 0.11.14

Any ideas how I can try to approach this? There's no stack trace.
I have a pretty convoluted proxy implementation, I've implemented the following methods:

`get, set, has, hasOwn, delete, keys, enumerate, getOwnPropertyNames, getPropertyNames, getOwnPropertyDescriptor, getPropertyDescriptor`

Is there a Proxy test suite set I can throw at it to see if I've implemented something incorrectly? Or any other way to see the source of the problem? I don't even know how to invoke half of the things I implemented :)

Any libraries that I can replace the Proxy object with? I think I saw one before but can't find it now.

EDIT: more details I forgot: It's not that there's no stack track, there's a stack trace from bluebird promise and it begins with `Promise$_rejectPromises`, which makes me think the error is related to [this problem](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2397) but I still don't know how find the source error with the problematic property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while looking for a Proxy replacement, I stumbled onto [this thread](https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect/issues/38), which says that this problem happens when something tries to use JSON.stringify() on the proxy.

I'm happy to say that implementing my own `toJSON()` method on the proxy object solved the problem.

Ahhh... so good to be back to 0.10.26